# Digital Ocean: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I have a droplet on Digital Ocean. Its credentials are shared with one of my friend. We used to connect to it via ssh as:
 `ssh root@IP_Address`
Now due to lack of concentration we did a mistake by running the following command while on the server:
`sudo chmod -R 777 /`
due to which server is not connecting anymore via anything (SSH/FTP/...)  and is giving the following error:
`ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

This is the output of `ssh root@IP_Address -vv`

`OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "IP_Address" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to IP_Address [IP_Address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/talha/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

Kindly help me ASAP as I don't have latest backup of hosted projects and databases.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As a strict minimum, login root via the DO console (see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-console-to-access-your-droplet) for instructions) and do

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(in other words set the access rights of `/root/.ssh` to `rwx------` and of `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `rw-------`. SSH won't trust the file if it can be accessed by other users.

You may also have to set the correct access rights to the files in /etc/ssh:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 300261 Aug 11  2016 moduli
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   1830 Sep 19  2016 ssh_config
-rw-------   1 root root    672 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    605 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root    227 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    177 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root    411 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     97 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root   1675 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    397 Oct  2  2016 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    338 Sep 19  2016 ssh_import_id
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   2598 Sep 19  2016 sshd_config
```